# Deleting all files in the src folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cmd

I'm doing the react tutorial and I'm having trouble with step 3.

I put the lines in the tutorial

> cd my-app
>   rm -f src/*

into my node.js command prompt and got "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't go in your `node.js` prompt. It's an OS command. If you are using linux, OSX, or ubuntu-on-windows, you should type it in your terminal.

If you are using windows, you can use `rmdir \S \Q src`

Comment: Furthermore, there's a `;` missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in linux or Mac OS you should do 
`cd my-app && rm -f src/*`

This will remove all the files in `src` and will keep the folders its files.

If you want to remove everything from src then use:
`cd my-app && rm -rf src/*`

Comment: Based on the error, "or batch file" implies that OS is windows